# LibGDX - GestureListener touch coords return in screen pixels, how convert to in-game world units?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touch

How can the coords returned from GestureListener (TouchDown method for example) be converted into world-unit coords.

EG. My device screen is 1080p, my game is set up to use 540x960 (portrait).
In my current example project (code below) the paddle moves along x-axis twice as quickly as my finger, hence the position being set is given in screen-pixels.

Of course in this exact example, I could easily just divide it by 2 as I know the gameworld-units are exactly half of the device-pixels, however what if I wanted to make my world size 150x150 units --or if I was testing on a device with different screen sizes??

```
package com.moneylife.breakingass;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;


public class BreakingAss extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Sprite bgSprite, bgCoverSprite, menu1Sprite;
    Paddle paddle;


    enum ScreenState { StartScreen, PlayScreen, GameOverScreen }
    ScreenState currentScreenState;

    public int DeviceScreenWidth, DeviceScreenHeight;
    public int WorldWidth = 540, WorldHeight = 960;
    public OrthographicCamera camera;
    int zAxis = 0;

    MyGestureDetector myGestureDetector;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        currentScreenState = ScreenState.StartScreen;
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        DeviceScreenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        DeviceScreenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        myGestureDetector = new MyGestureDetector();

        bgSprite = new Sprite(new Texture("bentoverass.jpg"));
        bgCoverSprite = new Sprite(new Texture("half1080coverup.png"));
        menu1Sprite = new Sprite(new Texture("menu1.jpg"));

        menu1Sprite.setSize(WorldHeight * DeviceScreenWidth / DeviceScreenHeight,WorldHeight);
        menu1Sprite.setPosition(0,0);

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(WorldWidth, WorldHeight);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, zAxis);
        camera.update();

        paddle = new Paddle(WorldWidth, WorldHeight);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(myGestureDetector));
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        paddle.update();
        camera.update();



        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        if (currentScreenState == ScreenState.StartScreen){
            menu1Sprite.draw(batch);
        }
        if (currentScreenState == ScreenState.PlayScreen){
            paddle.draw(batch);
        }


        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();

    }

    public class MyGestureDetector implements GestureDetector.GestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            if (currentScreenState == ScreenState.StartScreen) {
                if (x > 0) {
                    currentScreenState = ScreenState.PlayScreen;
                }
            }

            if (currentScreenState == ScreenState.PlayScreen){
                paddle.position = new Vector2(x - paddle.texture.getWidth() / 2, paddle.fixedYPosition);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
            if (currentScreenState == ScreenState.PlayScreen){
                paddle.position = new Vector2(x - paddle.texture.getWidth() / 2, paddle.fixedYPosition);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2, Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void pinchStop() {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Unproject the x and y with the camera, using a reusable Vector3 instance. `camera.unproject(tmpVec.set(x, y, 0)); //now tmpVec contains x and y for the game`

Comment: Ah genius! That is so much simpler than I had feared this might of been. thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting input coordinates always yields the coordinates of the screen. Logically because the input does not (need to) know about your game world. The camera is responsible for what is being drawn to the screen and the camera can be used to transform your screen coordinates to the coordinates of your world.

```
//Get screen coordinates
Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX, Gdx.input.getY, 0);
//Transform to world coordinates using the correct camera
camera.unproject(mousePosition);
//The mousePosition vector is changed in the above method and now contains the game world coordinates of the camera you used.
```

PS.
For your paddle you can make a transform method so you can use the `deltaX` and `deltaY` in the `pan` method. Since the delta's hand you the change in "pan"there is no need at all to transform between screen and world.

Comment: thank u also for pointing out deltaX. however the same issue occurs for this. eg. if I put  paddle.position.x += deltaX, but deltaX is in screen pixels and so it is moving the paddle (from centre) double as quick as my finger pans

Comment: oh wow! I sorted it but would be good to know if this is 'correct' solution... I just added line: deltaX = deltaX * (camera.viewportWidth / DeviceScreenWidth); inside the pan method  above the line i mentioined in comment above. it now works in this simple game so far

Comment: Seems like that works. But, if you use the camera properly you can use its `.zoom` to multiply `delta`. However, if you are setting your draw scale manually this won't work.

Comment: sorry i dont know what you mean by using the camera properly? do i have to 'unporject' the camera in all of my different objects classes (ie. Paddle, Ball, etc) to get the worldsize etc? up to now I have just passed the worldsizeXY ints and the currentpositions to each class via the update methods